# Key listener / logger using GetAsyncKeyState()

Tags: c++, winapi

I saw that a lot of people were able to use a for loop to determine the value of the key pressed, for example it would be GetAsyncKeyState(41) and they could therefore easily use a loop but for some reason it only works for me if I type in GetAsyncKeyState(0x41) etc, is there something I can do about this so I can loop through it instead of having to type each value individually?

```
int main()
{
while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F8))
{
    for(int i=65; i<90; i++)
    {

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i))
        {
        log << "HELLO DER";
        }
        Sleep(200);
     }
}
}
```

Comment: `41` != `0x41`.  `0x41` == `65` as you have in your loop there.

Answer (score 2):

`41` and `0x41` are two completely different values. The second one, `0x41` is hex for the decimal value 65, which is the ASCII code for 'A'. But I'm guessing you already know this since you initialise `i` to 65 (capital ASCII letters and VK codes match up).

Anyway your code almost works ok to an extent, assuming that you're trying to log key presses. Long story short is your loop delay is *way* too long, for it to iterate through every character it takes `200ms * 26 = 5.2 seconds`. Therefore if you type "AAAB" within 5.2 seconds only "AB" will be registered. But if the delay is too short then you might register a press more than once.

Read the [documentation for GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Anyway I'd probably choose a different function as mentioned in the remarks of the documentation above, something like [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as you'd usually use something like `GetAsyncKeyState` for registering key presses of hotkeys or something similar. ie. `GetAsyncKeyState` is good for wanting to know if a key *was* pressed, rather than how many times, the order of the presses, etc. A loop the way you have it just seems really prone to problems.

Also, don't do anything stupid logging keys...

**EDIT:** Actually `GetKeyboardState` still isn't that good of a solution. Setting a keyboard hook with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be a much better alternative. You could use the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook type to set a low level keyboard hook with a [LowLevelKeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback.

I did some Googling and there's an open-source macro program, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) that uses this method, which I guess you could take a look at if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Usage is pretty simple:

```
unsigned char kbstate[256];
if(!GetKeyboardState(kbstate))
{
   // can not get keyboard state
}else{
   for(int i=0; i<256: i++)
   {
      if(kbstate[i] & 0x1)
      {
         // the key is pressed, do something
      }
   }
}
```